# CKEditor doesn't see changes to plugin files?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to modify some basic plugins (the basic link dialog for instance), but it doesn't notice ANY of the changes I make to these files, even if I empty them. I've cleared my browser cache.

I notice **ckeditor.js** contains code similar to these files but as one big mess. Does it even read the plugin files, for plugins such as *Link* and *Youtube*? How can I modify these basic plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out **ckeditor.js** must be decompressed and modified.

The plugin files for built-in "plugins" are not actually used.